# Управляемая 3D модель в C#.NET

Tags: c#, winforms, 3d

Прошу помочь в решении задачи:
Есть некоторое количество 3-х мерных моделей. Так же имеется несколько моделей управления, которые по начальным условиям должны изменять положение этих моделей в пространстве, задавая им линейное перемещение и угловое вращение.
Подскажите как можно реализовать это все в рамках VisualStudio C# .NET

Comment: Не думаю что это возможно в Winforms или WPF. Скорее всего нужно создавать проэк XNA "Windows Game Library". И не думаю что начинающий осилит такую задачку.... Используй готовый движок лучше под такую задачу. Например Unity/

Comment: @Andrew - XNA разве не умер?

Comment: В каком формате ваши 3D-модели? Приведите больше подробностей.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov возможно и умер. Но про более современные аналоги не в курсе... В любом случае вряд ли он реализует через Winforms/WPF это :)

Comment: @Andrew - работа с 3D встроена в WPF, Для WinForms нужно подключить какую-нибудь библиотеку. То есть в обоих фреймворках задача реализуема. Вопрос лишь в том, какой формат моделей у автора. Но он молчит, как рыба об лёд.

Comment: Скорее всего, у автора просто домашка на winforms или wpf.

Посмотри [документацию WPF](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/3-d-graphics-overview) или эту простую [статью на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/164857/). Должно хватить

Comment: Модели в формате .MAX но я могу их перевести в любой другой форма, та как мне важны только сами модели их взаимное перемещение. По сути я делаю симулятор космического корабля Союз-ТМА и у меня есть 3д модель станции и самого корабля. Есть формат на которой я задаю начальные условия движения (угловые и линейные скорости, положение солнца, тензор инерции и т.д.) и есть модель движения которая по началу режима эти параметры моделирует. Мне надо сделать несколько окон на которых будет отображаться весь процесс в виде перемещения 3-х мерных объектов.